# Can anyone help me write a program in Python to output 5V from a USB port to control a relay?

Tags: usb, relay, power-electronics, sound

Can anyone help me write a program in Python to output 5 V from a USB port for only 2 min and then off for feeding a relay using only the power wires of the USB cable and without using an Arduino?

Comment: where would the python program run?

Comment: `with out using any Arduino` ... use a Raspbery Pi

Comment: What non-Arduino solutions you will accept? How would the non-Arduinoness relate to the Python program? Do you need to build a non-Arduino system that can control a 5V supply on an USB port with Python? What you really want makes no sense, please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: You can drive out a 5 V signal using an FTDI chip. Look for a "Serial Adapter" that uses an FTDI chip and is "FT232RL Compatible". Should be something in the USD10 range that comes in a nice plastic case with pins extruded. You can either then wire something (with good soldering skills) inside the case so as to gate the USB 5 V source to some output (at your risk) or else just use the logic compliant outputs that already exist for whatever purpose you have. A handy virtual com port driver class should be easily found for Python. I've not done it, but I've no doubt it would be easy to do.

Comment: If you are really good with your hands you can buy a glass-encapsulated reed relay ampule, hand-wire a coil around it, and pack that also into the cheap fob, leaving only the switched relay pins available outside the fob. Then it would be safer, too. (Assuming you did good, finely worked handicraft.)

Comment: The red and black colors in the USB Cable all time out put VCC = 5 V and Ground = 0 V , Can any one help me in writing a code for just out put VCC = 5 V for 120 sec only when there is a trigger signal the go off all the day ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64990689/control-the-power-of-a-usb-port-in-python

Comment: [Have a look here.](https://git.gniibe.org/cgit/gnuk/gnuk.git/tree/tool/hub_ctrl.py) That's a Python program to turn power on and off for USB hub ports.

Comment: @OsamaGhandourGeris In a general case you cannot write a Python program to control the 5V on an USB port, because it may not be software controllable to begin with, and if it is, it won't be software controllable by an user program, if it is on SoC GPIO pins controlled by driver.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way to get single bit I/O from a PC is to use a USB serial lead (they are all over AlliBayZon for a few $£€), and the pyserial library (not serial, that's something else) with python.

A USB to serial lead looks a bit like an ordinary USB lead at the A end, as it puts all the electronics into the plug housing.

Ideally, you want to get one that includes the handshake wires. These tend to be slightly more expensive than the ones with serial wires only, but they are easier to use. The handshake lines act as a one bit input and one bit output. Different manufacturers differ in which two of the four standard RS232 signals they provide, but they tend to be RTS and CTS.

The output wires carry 5 V, ground, and the signals are at typically 0 and 3.3 V. You will therefore need a resistor, transistor and a catch diode to switch the 5 V to your relay.

The python program is trivial. Once you have imported serial (it pips as pyserial, but imports as serial !), and opened a port, you can then set or reset the RTS, and read the state of the CTS (I think it's that way round, it was a long time ago!)

If instead you get a USB to serial adapter with only the Tx and Rx lines, or if you want to add a second bit of I/O to the one I've described above, then do not despair. You can get one bit output without a UART or Arduino on the end by interpretting the data that you can send down the Tx. There are several ways to do this. The Tx line will normally sit high.

- If you send a continuous stream of b'0Xff' bytes, then the filtered value of the voltage on the Tx line will drop to <0.5 V, low enough to be read by a transistor, CMOS or TTL as low.
- If you use a monostable as a threshold device, you will be able to detect the difference between short pulse sending b'0X80' and the long pulse of b'0Xff'.
- If you set the baud rate to 2400 baud, so the bit time is about 0.4 ms, you would be able to control a standard model servo to a few different positions!
- I've not tried this, but a 74HCT74 latch might be able to be used. Connect the Tx wire to CLOCK, hold the DATA input high, and connect an RC filter between Tx and the /CLEAR pin. Choose the RC filtering time constant such that its output is still high after the one bit b'0X80', but goes low with the 8 bit b'0Xff'. The short pulse therefore clocks the 1 through to set the latch output. The long pulse clears the latch.

Of course, if instead of a USB to serial lead, you use a plain USB lead to an Arduino, then you get a lot more options.

Comment: You gave this a lot more thought than I did. Nice answer! (Not a recommendation but [this one on `AlliBayZon`](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B1HYCN34) appears to have RTS & CTS included.)

Comment: @periblepsis I starting looking at the bits of a serial port to read my electricity meter consumption minute by minute. The meter does a 30 ms flash every Wh. At 200 baud, that's a sensible character, using a phototransistor to pull the RX line down. Read the serial input every minute, and the length of the received string is the number of flashes. There's a gotcha that pyserial will allow you to set any baud rate, and use it without reporting any error. Only some serial dongles' hardware actually supports obsolete baud rates, some I have just run at some random high rate when asked for 200.